# Scene Builder cambia "xmlns" de NetBeans al de Java 9 cuando tengo Java 8.0.162

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans-8.2, scenebuilder

Mi problema es que cuando abro mi archivo ***fxml*** en **NetBeans** me salen estas lineas de codigo las cuales son las correctas :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="345.0" minWidth="200.0" prefHeight="545.0" prefWidth="400.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <GridPane layoutY="25.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <columnConstraints>
```

Pero cuando modifico el ***fxml*** con el **Scene builder** y lo guardo me cambia esta parte de codigo en concreto:

- La buena :

  xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
- y cuando lo guardo la cambia por esta :

  xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"

Esto produce que me lance un error que en ocasiones no pasa nada pero a veces consigue que mi aplicacion no se abra. ¿Qué puedo hacer para que el **Scene Builder no me cambie la version del xmlns**?

Comment: Ya encontre la solución, por si a alguien le pasa lo mismo , es porque tenia la version 9 del Scene Builder y la solución para que funcionara perfecto es descargarse la version 8.4.1 de Scene Builder

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con versión 8?, yo solamente hallé versión 1 y 2 https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/javafxscenebuilder-1x-archive-2199384.html